# How to power a device with a LIPO battery correctly

Tags: low-power, lipo

I have a little device which is normally powered by 5V 2A.
But the manufacturer says it is compatible up to 16V 2A and I tested it with a powerbank which outputs 12V 2A.

Sadly this powerbank is a bit big to carry around, so I thought I could build something with a Lipo 3s Battery.

As far as I know 3S Lipos have around 12V. I asked my electronics teacher, and he said I could simply connect the device to the Lipo battery, but I do not want to kill a 300$ device so I want to have a second person checking it.

Will I be fine with simply connecting the battery to the device and it will self regulate the Ampere?

Thanks

Comment: savely isn't an english word, perhaps you mean "safely". The fact that's something is safe (no one gets hurt) doesn't mean it is a good idea. Instead of "safe" I would use "properly" or "correct": How to *correctly* power a device with a LIPO battery.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you, I am no native speaker so happy to get corrected :) I hope the title is more clear now.

Comment: *it will self regulate the Ampere?* Indeed the load will determine the **current**. Yes you can power the device from a 3S LiPo battery pack. You might want to add a **3 A fuse** between the battery pack and the device so that if something goes wrong the fuse will protect against excess current.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's about what I was thinking about. Something to protect it from too much current. I will look into a 3A fuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a little device which is normally powered by 5V 2A. But the manufacturer says it is compatible up to 16V 2A and I tested it with a powerbank which outputs 12V 2A.
>
> Will I be fine with simply connecting the battery to the device and it will self regulate the Ampere?

The maximum output voltage of a LiPo is 4.2V/cell or 12.6V for 3 cells in series when fully charged.  **IF** your device really will work safely on 13V it will be OK using a 3S LiPo.

You could use 2 x LiPo = 6V when fully discharged and 8.4V when fully charged.

IF the device draws 2A at 5V it will probably draw somewhat less at higher voltages as it probably has an internal switching regulator.
I at voltage V is probably ~~= 5/V x I_at_5V x k
Where k is probably in the range 1.1 - 1.2

Comment: Thank you. It does not matter if it doesn't accuratly hold on 12V, I think you shouldn't go below 11V with a lipo. This will still be enough. The device is a motor with some stuff around it, it outputs 0.45N at 5V and 1.1N at 14V so it should be inbetween at 11V. So it should power a bit better. So you say it will be safe to operate without any resistor or anything?

Comment: @TimothyLukasH. We can only go on what you tell us. IF it is rated to operate safely on 5V to 16V then it will be safe on 12.6V (3 LiPOs max V). 3 LiPos cells can go down to 9V, but it is better for them top not discharge to below 10V.